# On what queue should completionHandler be called to report immediate errors?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, completionhandler

I have an asynchronous function that takes a `completionHandler` as parameters.  It has typical result and error parameters.  The `completionHandler` is called after data, loaded from internet, is received.

There are a few pre-conditions in which an error must be immediately returned to the caller (e.g. when being passed an invalid request parameter).

Should these immediate errors be returned synchronously:

```
public private(set) var completionQueue: DispatchQueue

public func callAsync(requestData: String, completionHandler: @escaping (result: String?, error: Error?) -> Void)
{
    if <requestData is invalid>
    {
        completionHandler(result: nil, error: MyErrors.invalidRequestData)
    }

    ...
 }
```

Or, should the `completionHandler` always be called asynchronously, making no exceptions for errors found immediately?

```
    if <requestData is invalid>
    {
        completionQueue.async
        {
            completionHandler(result: nil, error: MyErrors.invalidRequestData)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be of the opinion that the caller of the `callAsync` function is expecting an asynchronous return.

The *speed* at which that happens is irrelevant. Ergo I would suggest the return should be asynchronous.

It's then up to the caller to properly handle the return 'data' on the main thread or otherwise as required. I wouldn't want to be mixing the threads in the `callAsync` implementation.

Answer (score 3):

If you only use `completionQueue` for the completion handler of that single function, then you can execute the `completionHandler` call synchronously on the queue, since you'll only be blocking further completion calls from the same function.

However, if you are using that `DispatchQueue` for anything else as well, for instance for executing the completion handler of other functions, then you shouldn't execute the completion handler synchronously, since you'll be blocking other functions from execution as well.

In general, I'd suggest executing completion handlers asynchronously and returning from the function after the completion handler call in case an error was encountered. This ensures that the function stops executing, but you're not blocking any other methods.

Comment: I think that deciding to call the `completionHandler` synchronously because of an external situation (i.e. others using the queue) is a bad idea.  Software elements should be as self-contained as possible, avoiding dependencies on external/changing environmental conditions.

Comment: @meaning-matters if you want to make it self contained, don't use the queue for anything else :) If you use the queue for other processes too, then you cannot disregard the fact that whether you dispatch to it synchronously or not will affect those other processes too